# Open Graph wrong title in action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I am having a problem with the wrong title appearing on an action on facebook. The title on the action is the wrong attribute. It is not generated from the og:title attribute.

**The setup is: order(action) a meal(object)**

Please see a couple of screenshots.

how it looks on fb:

[image]

How it looks in the json:

[image]

How the actual object looks:

[image]

Facebook open graph settings meal object:

[image]

Settings for the order object:

[image]

Edit:

I updated the attributes previously in the open graph settings.

Comment: Have you debugged your object page with the Facebook debugger already?

Comment: Yep. It shows the proper title for the open graph object. Just not when inspecting the graph API and my personal actions (https://graph.facebook.com/me/ - screenshot 2). The object is properly stored, the title in the action not,

Comment: There is actually a warning for the _og:updated_time_ not correctly being read (see link); off the top of my head I’m not sure if _2012-06-18 15:32:06 UTC_ is a valid ISO 8601 DateTime expression (resp. if it is one FB recognizes). Since it _might_ be related to FB (not) updating it’s internal cache version of the object, you should try and get that fixed. – https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fhekw.me%3A3000%2Forders%2F12%2Fopen_graph_object

Comment: Thanks. Fixed the error. Let's see : )

Comment: Not fixed. It is weird, the object has the correct title attribute. The action however does not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you used the same URL already and Facebook's cached the old title - you can clear the cache using [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) until the object is associated with many (I think 100) actions, after which point the title is locked even if you change the meta tags

Comment: Thanks for the info. The object can be properly parsed, the action however uses a different og:title than the debugger is able to fetch. e.g. "Pizza Calzone" in open graph, turns into "Restaurant Anatelo" as title in the action.

Comment: My question was effectively 'did you use the exact same URL before and publish many actions against it?' if you did, the original title is locked-in even if you change the meta tags on that URL in future

Comment: BTW, that object URL currently 404s for me: 
curl -i -A "facebookexternalhit/1.1" 'http://hekw.me:3000/orders/12/open_graph_object'
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Comment: Yep. that is the case. I used the same URL earlier. I will try to change that and see. Will ket you know.

Comment: Thanks! This is the problem. I just started up rails on a different port, all is working fine now.